# De un archivo .txt que contiene preguntas de opción múltiple, ¿Cómo obtengo cada pregunta con sus opciones y las guardo en un diccionario en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo txt que contiene muchas preguntas con sus respectivas opciones múltiples, este se vería algo así:

```
1.¿Cuál es la capital de Colombia?, responda
pensando bien su respuesta:

a.Bogotá
b.Cali
c.Medellín
d.Cartagena

2.Un martillo se usa para:

a.Golpear
b.Martillar
c.Dibujar
```

Y así pero más de 100 preguntas en el archivo txt, lo que aún no sé cómo realizar es extraer cada pregunta con sus repuestas en un diccionario de python (o si existe otra alternativa mejor, pues usar esa) para posterior evaluar las preguntas y verificar si el usuario respondió bien o no.

Esto es lo que llevo pero no toma toda la pregunta, ya que hay saltos de línea. Tampoco toma los números de cada pregunta completamente:

```py
def extraer_preguntas(archivoTXT: str):
    with open(archivoTXT, "r") as a:
        for linea in a:
            pregunta = re.search(r'\d\d\D+', linea)
            try:
                print(pregunta.group(0))
            except AttributeError:
                print("error")
```

Lo que obtengo:
`1.¿Cuál es la capital de Colombia?, responda`

Comment: No crees que sería mejor usar un formato CSV? Por ejemplo, con la segunda pregunta sería (todo en la misma línea): `Un martillo se usa para, Golpear, Martillar, Dibujar`. La forma que elijas para codificar la información hará que sea más fácil o más difícil decodificarla. En el caso de CSV es bastante simple.

Comment: Hola, buenas noches, puede ser una opción, intentaré después de probar las respuestas que me han dado. Gracias por el comentario!

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

El problema es que estás analizando línea por línea pero hay preguntas que como bien has dicho, abarcan más de una línea, lo mejor sería obtener todo el contenido de una vez y utilizar [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) para obtener todos los grupos de pregunta con sus respuestas de una sola vez y después procesar cada grupo por separado

Para procesar todo el contenido puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
with open(archivoTXT, "r", encoding='utf-8') as a:
    content = a.read()
```

Del contenido debes separar los grupos, como no sé bien como estén conformadas todas las preguntas y respuestas es posible (Casi seguro) que tengas que modificar el `regex` pero con las preguntas que pusiste se puede utilizar el siguiente `regex`

```
grupos = re.findall(r'(\d+\D+)', content)
```

Esto va a buscar algo que inicie con un número (Puede ser de uno o más dígitos, luego letras y va a terminar cuando encuentre otro número, por lo que si tienes números dentro del texto de tus preguntas o tus respuestas entonces tendrías que modificar el `regex`

Teniendo ya los grupos entonces podemos procesarlos para separar las pregutnas y las respuestas utilizando [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) junto con el siguiente `regex`:

```
elemento = re.split(r'(\d+\D+[:])', grupo)
```

Esto separará en una lista las preguntas y las respuestas

Y por último con una comprensión de listas obtenemos las respuestas y las separamos en una lista

```
respuestas = [i for i in elemento[2].split('\n') if len(i) > 0]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import re

def extraer_preguntas(archivoTXT: str):
    # Creamos un diccionario vacío
    d = {}
    with open(archivoTXT, "r", encoding='utf-8') as a:
        content = a.read()
        grupos = re.findall(r'(\d+\D+)', content)
    
    # Procesamos los grupos
    for grupo in grupos:
        # Separamos las preguntas de las respuestas
        elemento = re.split(r'(\d+\D+[:])', grupo)
        # Quitamos los saltos de línea de las preguntas
        pregunta = elemento[1].replace('\n', ' ')
        # Obtenemos una lista de respuestas
        respuestas = [i for i in elemento[2].split('\n') if len(i) > 0]
        # Agregamos la pregunta al diccionario
        d[pregunta] = respuestas
    
    # Regresamos el diccionario
    return d

print(extraer_preguntas('sample.txt'))
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente diccionario:

```
{'1.¿Cuál es la capital de Colombia?, responda pensando bien su respuesta:': ['a.Bogotá',
  'b.Cali',
  'c.Medellín',
  'd.Cartagena'],
 '2.Un martillo se usa para:': ['a.Golpear', 'b.Martillar', 'c.Dibujar']}
```

Que si guardas en una variable, por ejemplo:

```
preguntasProcesadas = extraer_preguntas('sample.txt')
```

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
print(preguntasProcesadas['2.Un martillo se usa para:'])
```

Y devuelve una lista con las respuestas:

```
['a.Golpear', 'b.Martillar', 'c.Dibujar']
```

Lo podrías mejorar para que separe el número de cada pregunta y que esa sea la llave del diccionario, pero eso ya te quedaría de tarea

Comment: Buenas noches, gracias por responder mi pregunta. Me parece muy buena opción tu respuesta ya que la salida se parece bastante a lo que tenía en mente, la estaré probando. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución procesa el archivo línea por línea, entregando cada pregunta-respuesta tan pronto se extraen del archivo.

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"(\d+)\.")

with open("cuestion.txt", "r") as cuestionario:
    respuestas = {}
    pregunta = {}
    while True:
        linea = cuestionario.readline()
        if not linea:
            #   Fin de archivo
            break

        if patron.match(linea):
            #   Leer el enunciado de la pregunta, que consta de
            #   una o más líneas terminadas con una línea en
            #   blanco.
            pregunta = []
            while linea.strip():
                pregunta.append(linea)
                linea = cuestionario.readline()

            #   Procesar las respuestas, una por línea,
            #   cada respuesta es un elmento en la lista
            respuestas = []
            linea = cuestionario.readline()
            while linea.strip():
                respuestas.append(linea)
                linea = cuestionario.readline()

            print("Pregunta:")
            print(''.join(pregunta))
            print("Alternativas:")
            print(''.join(respuestas))
```

El algoritmo consiste en leer líneas hasta identificar una que sea una pregunta: empieza con un número terminado con un punto. Eso lo reconoce la expresión regular.

La pregunta puede tener más de una línea. Se leen líneas del archivo y se acumulan en la lista `pregunta` hasta encontrar una línea en blanco, que separa pregunta de respuestas.

Terminada la pregunta, el siguiente bloque de líneas son las alternativas, las que se leen y acumulan de igual manera en `respuestas`. Si nos atenemos al principio de "una respuesta por línea", ya tienes separadas las respuestas en esta lista.

Luego sólo queda imprimir y repetir el ciclo.

#### Demo

El código anterior produce:

```
Pregunta:
1.¿Cuál es la capital de Colombia?, responda
pensando bien su respuesta:

Alternativas:
a.Bogotá
b.Cali
c.Medellín
d.Cartagena

Pregunta:
2.Un martillo se usa para:

Alternativas:
a.Golpear
b.Martillar
c.Dibujar


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: No podrias iterar sobre el archivo en lugar de usar readline? Es decir, convertir el objeto de archivo en un iterador y usar next y bucles for?

Comment: @DanteS. Sería interesante que publicaras esa alternativa para efectos de comparación.

Comment: [Hecho!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/555588/158880)

Comment: Hola, gracias a ambos por tomarse el tiempo de responder mi duda. Estaré probando tu respuesta @CandidMoe, ahorita ando un poco ocupado, pero la testearé. Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Para lidiar con este caso podemos usar un iterador creado a partir del archivo.

#### Que es un iterador?

Un iterador es un objeto que va devolviendo cosas conforme se llama a su método `__next__` (esta función es internamente llamada por la función next). Cuando recorres algo con un for, internamente utiliza la función iter al objeto y va usando next hasta que se agota el iterador (es decir, no tiene nada más que devolver).

Los iteradores son muy utiles, pues nos permiten ir recuperando datos sin necesidad de tenerlos almacenados en memoria (incluso es posible crear iteradores infinitos).

En el caso de los archivos, el iterador que se puede crear a partir de estos nos permite recorrer un archivo linea por linea sin usar readline ni cargar datos al cohete en memoria.
Lo unico malo de iterar sobre un archivo, es que no es posible usar seek mientras esto sucede. Pero en este caso, el uso de seek no será necesario.

#### La función iter

La función iter llama internamente al método `__iter__` de un objeto. Este método debe devolver un iterador, que puede ser el mismo objeto pasado como argumento a iter. Es decir, A VECES se cumple que `iter(obj) is obj`.

#### Finalmente, la solución

El siguiente código produce un diccionario donde la clave es el número de pregunta y el valor un diccionario con la pregunta y una lista de respuestas. Si no te sirve lo que crea, podés usar este código y estos conceptos de base para adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

###### Código

```
from pprint import pprint
import io
import re

# Para evitar crearme un archivo en mi pc
# Hice uso del modulo io, pero funcionará del mismo modo
# Si abres el archivo desde el disco.

file = io.StringIO(
"""
1.¿Cuál es la capital de Colombia?, responda
pensando bien su respuesta:

a.Bogotá
b.Cali
c.Medellín
d.Cartagena

2.Un martillo se usa para:

a.Golpear
b.Martillar
c.Dibujar
""")

patron = re.compile(r"(\d+)\.")
preguntas = {}

# guardamos en una variable un iterado
# que se encargará de devolver
# cada linea del archivo
file_iter = iter(file)

for line in file_iter:
    m = patron.match(line)

    # Si m NO ES el objeto None...  
    if(m is not None):
        preguntas[int(m[1])] = dct = dict(pregunta=line, respuestas=[])

        # Iteramos sobre el iterador antes guardado
        # Esto avanza desde la ultima linea leida.
        for line in file_iter:
            # Si la linea, quitando los espacios y saltos de linea
            # al inicio y al final resulta en una cadena vacía
            # (esto es basicamente una linea en blanco o con puros espacios)
            if(not line.strip()):
                # Finalizo el bucle for
                break
                
            dct["pregunta"] += line

        for line in file_iter:
            if(not line.strip()):
                break
            # agregamos la respuesta quitando los saltos de linea y espacios al final.
            dct["respuestas"].append(line.rstrip())

pprint(preguntas)
```

###### Produce

```
{1: {'pregunta': '1.¿Cuál es la capital de Colombia?, responda\n'
                 'pensando bien su respuesta:\n',
     'respuestas': ['a.Bogotá', 'b.Cali', 'c.Medellín', 'd.Cartagena']},
 2: {'pregunta': '2.Un martillo se usa para:\n',
     'respuestas': ['a.Golpear', 'b.Martillar', 'c.Dibujar']}}
```

###### Descripción

Lo siguiente es una estructura que representa como el iterador es recorrido:

- Inicio el recorrido del archivo
- Si la linea coincide con la regex...

  - Guardo la linea
  - Recorro todas las demás lineas, concatenandola a al grupo de lineas anteriores, hasta que la linea esté "vacía" (ver comentarios del código para ver que significa vacía en este contexto)
  - Asumo que lo que sigue es una respuesta por linea hasta encontrarme con otra linea vacía.
- Continúo leyendo el archivo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder mi pregunta. Tu nivel de programación es bastante superior al mío, probaré tu respuesta pero a la vez aprenderé de ella para poder aplicarla correctamente y probablemente (muy seguramente) te estaré preguntando sobre tu respuesta. Gracias :)

Comment: He tenido en cuenta la diferencia denivel, por esa razon me dedique a explicar que es un iterador y como funciona el código ;) Escucho tus preguntas y suerte c: